# Vue display date only from dateTime

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

I am using `moment.js` to format date/time on Vue. DateTime value on object is `2020-05-20 T 06:00:00.000 Z` format. Is there a way to reduce one hour from that time and display only time using `moment.js`?

**View**

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>How to deduct 1 hour and display only time rather than dateTime</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
      {{todo.dateTime}} /** its suppose to reduce one hour and display only time **/
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { id:'1', dateTime: "2020-05-20T06:00:00.000Z"},
      { id:'2', dateTime: "2020-05-20T010:00:00.000Z"},
    ]
  },
  methods: {

  }
})
```

**Below is my code on jsfiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/e5mrz34k/7/

Comment: What do you mean by _"reduce one hour"_? Could you please show some examples of the output you want?

Comment: @Phil date for firs object is 2020-05-20T06:00:00.000Z. Where the time is 06:00:00. Is there a way to deduct one hour using moment js and display 05:00:00 instead of 06:00:00

Comment: FYI `2020-05-20T010:00:00.000Z` is invalid. The hour `10` should not have a leading zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always make some [filters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html) to do the time manipulation and formatting.

For example...

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { id:'1', dateTime: "2020-05-20T06:00:00.000Z"},
      { id:'2', dateTime: "2020-05-20T10:00:00.000Z"},
    ]
  },
  filters: {
    dtSubtract (dt, duration, unit) {
      return moment.utc(dt).subtract(duration, unit)
    },
    dtFormat (dt, format) {
      return moment.utc(dt).format(format)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-5oApc/wMda1ntIEK4qoWJ4YItnV4fBHMwywunj8gPqc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>How to deduct 1 hour and display only time rather than dateTime</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
      <em>
        {{ todo.dateTime | dtFormat('HH:mm:ss') }}
      </em>
      becomes
      <strong>
        {{ todo.dateTime | dtSubtract(1, 'hour') | dtFormat('HH:mm:ss') }}
      </strong>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```